# How do you create a virtual network interface on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

On linux, it's possible to create a tun interface using a tun driver which provides a "network interface psuedo-device" that can be treated as a regular network interface.  Is there a way to do this programmatically on windows?  Is there a way to do this without writing my own driver?

Comment: How did u do that on linux ?

Comment: For windows 7/8 http://superuser.com/questions/339465/creating-a-virtual-nic-on-windows-7/339475#339475

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this on XP with the [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](https://web.archive.org/web/20150217152013/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013) which is a driver for a virtual network card.

On newer Windows version: [Installing the Microsoft Loopback Adapter in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2777200/installing-the-microsoft-loopback-adapter-in-windows-8-and-windows-ser)

Comment: Is there anything better, it seems to require restarts? Where as I can see that Virtualbox can create adapters without needing restarts.

Comment: For windows 7/8 http://superuser.com/questions/339465/creating-a-virtual-nic-on-windows-7/339475#339475

Comment: Cannot downvote as I do not have enough reputation but the link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

@Tim
Depending on the licensing you might be able to use the TUN/TAP driver that is part of OpenVPN, see [here](http://www.varsanofiev.com/inside/using_tuntap_under_windows.htm) for details.

Answer (score 1):

## Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter

not sure if that can be done programatically, but for manually setup:
you can use a "Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter" on windows 11 (works on older windows versions, too, i guess)

1. right click start button -> Device manager
2. select your PC at the top (otherwise menu item will be missing)
3. menu "Action" -> "Add legacy hardware"
4. next -> "install the hardware that I manually selectron from a list (Advanced)" -> next
5. select "network adapters" -> next -> wait until list is loaded
6. In the Manufacturer list, select Microsoft. In the Model list, select Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter
7. next -> finish
8. can be found where the other network adapters are. It is usually called "Ethernet 2" or something like that.
9. can be uninstalled in the device manager

source: https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us00693656/

Comment: Tested on Windows 10 and works like a charm ❤️

Answer (score 0):

In the Singularity project, Microsoft research communicates with the singularity VM through a "loopback" adapter. Maybe that'd help?

Running it is easy so it may be something fun to do anyway. :)

http://research.microsoft.com/os/Singularity/