# Fiddler: Can it be used as a proxy server with arbitray source IP addr

Tags: fiddler, proxy-server

As title mentioned, can achieve it with Fiddler?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to reword your question, as it's entirely unclear as to what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845756/how-to-tamper-with-source-ip-address-on-windows/1845775#1845775), it's not possible to use an arbitrary ip with http. You have to use existing proxies from different places to simulate visitors coming from different places.