# self signed certificate working fine on windows but giving error on Android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, self-signed

I have created a self signed certificate configured on IIS 7, it is working fine on windows machines after importing CA. I have imported same CA in Andriod but website is giving error "The name of the site doesn't match the name of certificate", please help in this regard.

Comment: What are (1) the names in the certificate, and (2) the name used by Android?

Comment: i am testing on android 4.2.2 which comes with SNI support while IIS 7 doesn't support SNI, is this the cause of error???

Comment: If this is a private LAN, add a virtual adapter to Windows, and have IIS 7 bind the site to the virtual adapter to serve the proper certificate. See, for example, [How do you create a virtual network interface on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-network-interface-on-windows). If its public facing, then get another IP or upgrade to IIS 7.5 (or is it 8.0?).